Obscure tv show/movie/tv movie about two men with Telekinesis and Pyrokinesis
Looking for an obscure movie, pre 2000's. A man with telekinesis is hit by a car, but protects himself with is mind. He wakes up in a hospital and has to escape, possibly with the help of a woman(?). He meets up with a black short order chef that has Pyrokinesis (fire control).
In one scene, they chase/are chased in a car. Telekinetic guy uses his powers to make their car go faster (or maybe slow the other one down?) and gets a nosebleed. The pyro burns out the other cars tires.
I also think I remember a black kid with telepathy, but I could be wrong about that. I saw bits of the film as a kid and can't remember much else.

The question's title can be improved; try to make it a bit more meaningful, someone seeing "Obscure pre-2000s tv-movie about Pyrokinesis" might trigger someone's memory a bit more effectively; it's also more search-friendly.

Sounds like you're after Yesterday's Target from 1996. From Rotten Tomatoes:

In this sci-fi thriller which opens in the year 2025, researchers have been able to create a new race of people with remarkable mental powers, such as ESP. In order to insure their safety, three of these gifted individuals must be sent back in time 30 years to protect a young man who years later will later come to their rescue. 

Of these 3 people, Daniel Baldwin's character has telekinesis (and at some point makes a car go faster with his mind) and T.K. Carter's character is a cook who can control fire. Here's the trailer:



